# ODI 12.2.1 variable not setting the value dynamically in Jython procedure

Tags: oracle, variables, jython, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

We are facing issue with setting ODI variable in Jython script. Any help on below issue is great.

Problem statement: We have to get the OS name from the current Operating system and based on Operating system, we have to execute ODIOSCommand (Linux or Windows).

But we are not able to set the OS name in a variable (i.e either using Jython variable OR ODI variable). It seems to be taking only first value(Default value) and Not setting  the value dynamically.

Issue:- We are not able to set ODI variable through the jython script and get the dynamic value.

We are trying to set a ODI variable through the Jython script and this variable value is used to run ODIOS command to create a text file on respective operating system.

Please find the details below.
•Create a procedure to run jython script.
•Run the command “os.get_os_type()” and get OS type.
•If OS type is windows or NT then set ODI variable(#IsWindows) to “Yes”.
•If OS type is Linux then set the ODI variable(#IsWindows) to “NO”.
•Evaluate ODI variable(#IsWindows)if it has value YES then run windows command to create text file else run Linux command to create the text file on Linux machine.

Existing code in 11g version:-

import os

if os.get_os_type() == 'nt':

```
 cmd = 'dir "#ProcessingFolder*.xml" /s /b /a:-d > "#CurrFileName"'
```

os.system(cmd)

else:

```
 os.system("ls -d #ProcessingFolder*.[x,X][m,M][l,L] > #CurrFileName")
```

Below jython code we are trying to set the ODI variable in ODI 12.2.1 because above code is not workign in ODI 12.2.1:-

import os

if os.get_os_type() == 'nt':

## POG_IMPORT_3.IsWindows = 'YES'

else:

#POG_IMPORT_3.IsWindows= 'NO'

Once above procedure Is executed , We are using “Refresh” variable to get the latest value in the variable i.e. SELECT '#IsWindows '  FROM DUAL.

And Evaluate variable to check if it has “YES” or “NO”.

But "#IsWindows" variable is not setting/holding the value which is set during run-time.

Note: This is a project which is migrated from 11.1.1.7 to 12.2.1 and we are first time creating variable in 12.2.1.

Is 12.2.1 variable creation/use different in 12.2.1 version?

Any hint on how to store the runtime value to the ODI variable is very helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the variables are STRONGLY TYPED. This means that if your variable #isWindows should be prefixed as "#BIAPPS.IsWindows". This did not occur in 11g but 12c requires ownership, so do not type the variable in but consume it from the below pane where the local variables are stored.